# Align dots while preserving spacing between them and page number

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, tocloft

I'm a bit fastidious and I would like that dots (roughly added by the way) keep aligned while preserving the space between them and the page number. I think the screenshot will be pretty clear.

EDIT: Points need to be aligned, by this, I mean that the last point of each line must be aligned to the next one, and so on.

[image]

To solve the issue, you can remove the bold font or not, as you wish.
I tried to change the dot separation width but It just doesn't work.

Here, the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% Titres des sections
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.}

% Table des matières
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}                    % Nombre max de niveau dans la table des matières

\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1 em}        % Espacement entre les titres des parties
\renewcommand{\cftpartdotsep}{\cftdotsep}   % Points entre le titre des sections et le numéro de page

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.50 em}      % Espacement avant les titres des sections
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.25 em}          % Espacement entre la marge le numéro des sections
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.25 em}        % Espacement entre le titre des sections et le numéro
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}    % Points entre le titre des sections et le numéro de page

\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.25 em}   % Espacement avant les titres des sous-sections
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{4.5 em}        % Espacement entre la marge le numéro des sous sections
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2.875 em}    % Espacement entre le titre de la section et le numéro des sous sections

\begin{document}
\part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
\section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
\subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
\subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}

\section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
\subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
\subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
\subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}

\part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
\section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
\subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
\subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}

\section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
\subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
\subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
\subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: b]

It was made  a patch to the command `\cftdotfill`  to get the right alignment of the dots. Also added more content to check the behavior with greater page numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5 cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% Titres des sections
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.}

% Table des matières
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}                    % Nombre max de niveau dans la table des matières

\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1 em}        % Espacement entre les titres des parties
\renewcommand{\cftpartdotsep}{\cftdotsep}   % Points entre le titre des sections et le numéro de page

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.50 em}      % Espacement avant les titres des sections
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.25 em}          % Espacement entre la marge le numéro des sections
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.25 em}        % Espacement entre le titre des sections et le numéro
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}    % Points entre le titre des sections et le numéro de page

\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.25 em}   % Espacement avant les titres des sous-sections
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{4.5 em}        % Espacement entre la marge le numéro des sous sections
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2.875 em}    % Espacement entre le titre de la section et le numéro des sous sections


% ********************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftdotfill}[1]{%
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \def\@tempb{\cftnodots}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \hfill
    \else
%   \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern #1 mu\hbox{\cftdot}\mkern #1 mu$}\hfill% old line
    \leaders\hbox to 4mm{\hss\cftdot\hss}\hskip 4mm plus1fill% new line <<<<<<<<<<<
    \fi
}
\makeatother
% ********************************************  

\begin{document}
    
    \part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
    \section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
    \subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
    \subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}
    \newpage
    \section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
    \subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
    \subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
    \subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}
    \newpage
    \part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
    \section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
    \subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
    \subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}
    
    \section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
    \subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
    \subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
    \subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{9}
    
    \part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
    \section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
    \subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
    \subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}
    \newpage
    \section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
    \subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
    \subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
    \subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}
    \newpage
    \part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
    \section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
    \subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
    \subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}
    \newpage
    \section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
    \subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
    \subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
    \subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}
    \setcounter{page}{99}
                    
    \part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
    \section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
    \subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
    \subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}
    \newpage
    \section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
    \subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
    \subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
    \subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}
    \newpage
    \part{Dolor pariatur laboris}
    \section{Fugiat proident amet officia nisi.}
    \subsection{Ullamco aliqua reprehenderit culpa excepteur velit sunt id.}
    \subsubsection{Adipisicing dolore nisi ullamco sint est incididunt tempor sunt.}
    \newpage
    \section{Sint aliquip ea sit amet consequat fugiat.}
    \subsection{Aliqua do veniam ut duis elit occaecat.}
    \subsubsection{Reprehenderit incididunt duis adipisicing nisi.}
    \subsubsection{Fugiat adipisicing commodo occaecat ut dolor elit dolor mollit labore duis labore in ipsum enim.}
        
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I misspoke, but the problem is not really the page number but the points.

In fact, depending on the type of title, the last point of the line of points is not aligned with those of the next (or previous) line.

[That's what I mean](https://imgur.com/a/8LEHWF5)

Comment: Oh great, It's perfect. Thanks!